# open (the/a) scoring for South Korea

Tags: articles

Hi I'm reading a sport article and saw this:

> Kim Young-gwon opened the scoring for South Korea against Germany in added time.
>
> [Link to CNN article](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/06/27/football/germany-south-korea-sweden-mexico-world-cup-2018-group-f-spt/index.html)

I don't know why they used definite article because to me, it can be just "a scoring" or just no article at all "opened scoring". 
So I thought of the reason and guessed that the reader is already informed of this scoring in the article's beginning and the line is for the picture, making it an already-known fact for the reader so it's natural to use definite article "the"
Is my guess right?

And one more question:
Why using "in added time" instead of "in an added time" or "in the added time"?
From what I know, I think it should be in "an" added time since it's not specified nor introduced to the reader about how much time was given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The scoring** means "the sum total of goals scored during the entirety of the game".

There cannot be ***a* scoring** when the word has that meaning.  It does not refer to a single goal.

The phrase **added time** is a term that means "a span of time customarily tacked onto the end of the half to account for play stoppage during the game", usually as a result of injury.  It is rare that there will be no added time. Since this span of time is *customarily* added, we find the definite article, **the**, or the zero-article, simply **added time**, either of which can be used with something which is customary and/or known everywhere because it is universal and familiar. And the word **added** has acquired a specific meaning and can suffice as the specifier.

***an* added time** would refer to a stretch of time added *incidentally* to the game, implying the opposite of "customary".

Compare:

> The car manufacturer was introducing a new roadster. Their automotive
>    engineers spent a lot of time tweaking **the** sound of **the** exhaust system.

A hundred years from now, when cars will no longer be running on fossil fuel, and people might no longer be *familiar* with internal combustion engines, as these engines might exist only in museums, you might find this sentence:

> The car manufacturer was introducing a new roadster back in 2018. Their automotive engineers spent a lot of time tweaking **a** sound from **an** exhaust system, which customers back in those days found especially thrilling.

Comment: Is this phrase common in British English or the sports world? It sounds weird to my ear (from the title I thought it had something to do with writing a soundtrack for South Korea), but that could easily be because it's not American or is sports jargon (or a particular sport's jargon).

Comment: Yes, **opened the scoring** is a common phrase on both sides of the Atlantic, and has been in use for more than 100 years. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22opened%20the%20scoring%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1906&lr=lang_en

Comment: As a native British English speaker but not a sports fan this sentence left me stumped, I must admit.

Comment: Tᴚoɯɐuo, your explanation is unbelievably helpful and enlightening! Now I can understand how and when articles are used properly in those contexts. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it:))